# Division using MySQL with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking at the previous post on "division using count" and seems to be having problem in the divide by part. Below is my query, I get the results but the results is wrong because the "divide by" with `count(*)` seems to be using the count of all the stores and not group by the stores.

What I am interested is the "divide by "should also be based on the number of counts for that particular store. my second part of the query for the divide by should be something like "`select count(*) *100 group by stores`"

```
SELECT store, CAST(((  
    SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 -
    SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS signed) AS NPS
FROM npsnetsuite
WHERE SCORE IS NOT NULL group by STORE;
```

example:

```
Store A has got total count of 7 rows
Store B has got total count of 12 rows
```

the division should be

```
XX/7 for Store A
XX/12 for Store B
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Date       Store    Score   Case When between 9-10  case when 0-6
18/04/2016  A         9                  1  
20/04/2016  A         8     
26/04/2016  A         10                 1  
29/04/2016  A         8     
30/04/2016  A        10                  1  
01/05/2016  A        10                  1  
06/05/2016  A        8      
11/05/2016  A        10                  1  
23/05/2016  A        10                  1  
04/06/2016  A         6                               1
09/06/2016  A         8     
08/06/2016  A        10                  1  
05/04/2016  B         4                               1 
07/04/2016  B        10                  1  
18/04/2016  B        10                  1  
27/04/2016  B         8     
01/05/2016  B         9                  1  
13/05/2016  B        10                  1  
13/06/2016  B         1                              1
14/06/2016  B         6                              1
```

Sample Data:
[image: Sample Data]

**Desired Output:**

```
Store A 50
Store B 13
```

So basically `Store A is (7-1)/12 * 100 = 50`.

`7` is the count when case when for score `9 to 10` and `1` is the count when case when for score `0 to 6`. So the first part which i have got it correct is  count of number of score 9to10 MINUS count of number of score 0to6 for each store. And i need to divide by the number of count for that particular stores. As above example Store A contain 12 rows and Store B contain 8 rows. My current query is taking the count of all stores.

Thank you

Comment: Some sample input and output would go a long way here.

Comment: Post the data sample you're using.

Comment: Desired output: Store A 50
Store B 13 so basically Store A should be (7-1)/12 whereby 12 is the total store belonging to Store A.

Comment: Add it into your question

Comment: Your desired output is confusing, please add more detail and add it in your question not in the comment.

Comment: thank you Shah for the suggestion. I have edited my post:) my problem is my table and i copy and paste the columns is not alligned:(

Comment: Why didn't `9-10` column is true for the 5th row from last? and are these `Case When between 9-10`  `case when 0-6` really your columns or you just added to show us?

Comment: HI Shah. its not a column. it is in my SQL Calculations. 5th row from last do you mean Date 27/04/2016 for Store B? That is score 8 so the case when 9-10 will not be true and I dont need to take into account. Sorry is my questions very vague?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad I took it wrong. You're being very clear though.

Comment: I executed your query on your given data and I got the your **desired results**. What results are you getting by running this query?

Comment: Thank you Shah..i just tried with below query and it gave me the result above. Not sure the efficiency of my query but I really appreciate your help ~~(the first query above i posted gave me a different result)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all~  Finally, managed to get the results as per above output through this query:):

```
select a.STORE, round((a.count_one / b.count_two) * 100) as final_count from 
(select SCORE, STORE, SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 -
  SUM(CASE WHEN SCORE BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_one from npsnetsuite where SCORE IS NOT NULL group by STORE) a,
(select SCORE, STORE, count(*) as count_two from npsnetsuite where  SCORE IS NOT NULL group by STORE) b
where a.STORE = b.STORE and a.SCORE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You previous query also gave me the same results your this query gives. I don't know why did you put so much effort to write another query. And this one is actually very bad as compare to the first one in performance.

Comment: OMG, you are right Shah!!! the first query gave the same result. I must have been confused..sorry. I think i was over worried why i didn't have a,store=b.store to get the both divisor and dividend to have match the same store. thank you so much~